# Average data series using interpolation due to irregular intervals

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, sampling, mean, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am planning to average driving routes (more specifically a 1-dimensional deviation of a optimal route) relative to the distance travelled. My problem is that I have this data sampled in (constant-interval) time, not needed distanc.

However, of course the distance travelled (on a specific axis) is depending on speed, steering angle relative to the reference axis etc and thus not in regular intervals, which makes it hard for me to find a way to average over it...

Using Jfreechart I could plot all taken routes [image]

I assume they do **some kind of interpolation,** as I simply specified the distance travelled as x coordinate... which is basically **what I want to do, but I require an averaged series instead of multiples**. Can anyone give me a hint on what to look for / or how you would implement such an average over irregular series?

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you produce your averaged path by simply taking all `Lane Deviation` values at a certain `Distance` and average them? Example: At `Distance` = 200 your paths seem to have about 20-30 values between 2 and 4.2, taking all of them and averaging should yield something around 3.5 probably, voilà. Or am I missing?

Comment: Hey, @Denwid, this is not travelled as there (as I mentioned) are no specific distance intervals, only time intervals. Hence, I can't specify distance steps which exist for all series.

Comment: I may have found what I am looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969188/how-to-get-y-value-from-x-value-in-jfreechart

Comment: Ah sorry, the plot was misleading it seemed you have all values.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for that but also mentioned it in the text :)